# User timings using Google analytics in Android app

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am using hitbuilder() of ga to track resource loading time in my Android application. But its not showing anything on my ga console under app speed tab. When I set dry run enabled its showing me proper logs with utt. Need help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proper builder (`HitBuilders.TimingBuilder`) for events to show up in *app speed*